# C# Multi-language Localize resources Windows Forms - how to do not apply empty resource for controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, resources, multilingual

I can't use normal localization for Windows Forms for project i am currently working on (it's not support multi-language resx files well due to merge system).

So i wrote workaround for that:

```
private static readonly ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form_GUI));

private void ApplyRes(Control.ControlCollection cc, CultureInfo ci)
    {
        foreach (Control c in cc)
        {
            if (excludeControls.Contains(c.Name))
                continue;
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, ci);

            if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
                ApplyRes(c.Controls, ci);
        }
    }
```

The problem is for some cases, i am not sure if this connected to deep level of item or something else. I am getting blank values after language change.

So if there a way to check if localize resource contains value for control than change it, if not - let it stay in default (English) language.

**Totaling:** do not try to apply empty value.

Also want to mention i am using in form custom component, for some reason it do not switch back to english language, once any other language was chosen, but normally switch to other localized languages. Other forms elements work ok.

*Is there any way to do so? Will be appreciative for help! :)*

Comment: What is content of resource files and what are the controls that you experience problem with them? Can you reproduce the problem using a sample resource file and a sample code?

Comment: I see two bugs, you forgot to localize the form object itself and excludeControls prevents the excluded control's children from being localized.  Otherwise this is the code that runs when "normal localization" is used.  So if "normal" doesn't work then very few reasons to assume that this can work.  There is no such thing as an "empty" resource.  You can only get help with a minimal repro project.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei, i have main form which use CustomControl which i am adding to it programmatically (not via visual Designer).

Comment: @Hans Passant, Excluded controls do not have childs, that's why i didn't check for this.

Comment: I think i found some solution not very handy tho - added all texts lines from CustomControl resx file to Main form file (making sure it's not have same on Main form). So localize files i will update same way :)

Comment: Wish to find normal way of doing this. Main problem that Main Application to which i am writing module do not work (do not compile) standard satellite resource file cause of merge tool it use. So i can't use just standard way of doing this and have to rename all satellite files from GUI.ru.resx  to GUI-ru.resx - so i will have this resource file after compile and than can manually load it -_-